# Python: List Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have the following code:

```
letters = 'defghijklmno'
K = {letters[i]:(i*i-1) for i in range(len(letters))}
```

I understand that I'm iterating over the sequence variable of letters and how the value is calculated, but I'm confused over how the key gets set to the individual characters of the string. Especially because I have letters being indexed as my key. Basically, I'm just trying to figure out how python evaluates this expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand it, it helps to look at the individual parts of what happens. A `for i in range(len(letters))` loop does not loop over the individual characters of the letters, but over the indizes of the string. That is because you can access indidual characters of a string using their index. So `letters[0]` refers to the first character, `letters[1]` to the second, and `letters[len(letters)-1]` to the last.

So, let’s look at the keys of the dictionary individually:

```
>>> [letters[i] for i in range(len(letters))]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

So you get all the letters individually in the original order.

Now, let’s look at the values of the dictionary:

```
>>> [(i*i-1) for i in range(len(letters))]
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80, 99, 120]
```

So, now we have both keys and values; all that the dictionary comprehension does now is link those keys to the values—in the order above.

Answer (score 3):

That `dict` comprehension is basically a synonym for:

```
k = {}
for i in range(len(letters)):
    k[letters[i]] = i*i - 1
```

The difference is that it creates a new scope instead of using the outer scope:

```
>>> letters = 'defghijklmno'
>>> K = {letters[i]:(i*i-1) for i in range(len(letters))}
>>> i          # was defined in an inner scope
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>> k = {}
>>> for i in range(len(letters)):
...     k[letters[i]] = i*i - 1
... 
>>> i     # still defined!
11
```

Answer (score 3):

Explanation:

```
>>> letters = 'defghijklmno'
>>> range(len(letters))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

This means, that

```
>>> [letters[i] for i in range(len(letters))]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

At the same time

```
>>> [(i*i-1) for i in range(len(letters))]
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80, 99, 120]
```

So, your dictionary comprehension builds dict of pairs `'d':-1, 'e':0, 'f':3, ...` (etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, this is a rather bad way of doing it. Looping by indices is a really bad practice in Python (it's slower, and horrible to read), so the much better way is this:

```
letters = 'defghijklmno'
K = {letter: (i*i-1) for i, letter in enumerate(letters)}
```

All this is is a simple [dictionary comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw). When we loop over a string, we get the individual characters making it up. We use the `enumerate()` builtin to give us matching numbers, and then produce a dictionary from the letter to the number squared, minus one.

If you are struggling with the comprehension itself, it's equivalent to a for loop (except faster), and I recommend you watch [my video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) for a complete explanation with examples of dictionary comprehensions alongside it's cousins (list/set comprehensions and generator expressions).

Answer (score 0):

The second line is a dictionary comprehension. It is like a normal list comprehension or generator expression except that it generates key value pairs which are then used to form a dictionary.

The code is roughly equivalent to

```
letters = 'defghijklmno'
K = {}
for i in range(len(letters)):
    key = letters[i]
    val = (i*i-1)
    K[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the Dict comprehension as loop like

```
K = {} # empty dict
for i in range(len(letters)): # i goes from 0 to 11
    K[letters[i]] = i*i-1
```

so in the single iterations you have

```
K['d'] = -1
K['e'] = 0
K['f'] = 3
# ...
```

and so on. The dict comprehension is just a shorter (and in the opinion of most python programmers) more elegant way to write this loop.

Answer (score 0):

For every `i` from `i == 0` to `i == 11` (index of the last letter in `letters`), an entry is added to the resulting dictionary where the key is `letters[i]` and its associated value is `i*i-1`. This gives:

```
K['d'] == -1
K['e'] == 0
K['f'] == 3
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually iterating over the letters of `letters`, per se; rather, you're iterating over the *length* of `letters`, by varying `i` from `0`, to `1`, to `2`, ..., to `11`. As you vary `i`, you create a dictionary entry whose key is the `i`th letter of `letters` and whose value is `i*i - 1`.

In other words, you create a dictionary, each entry of which consists of a letter (key) `k` from `letters`, paired with a value equal to `k`'s index squared, minus `1`.

You can read the dictionary comprehension in plain English as: the dictionary of all letters (keys) `k` from `letters` with index `i`, paired with the value `i*i - 1`.